# "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" error while querying Oracle DB using Spark

Tags: oracle, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I was trying to load data from Oracle database using Spark data source API.

Since I need to load data by query, I used the query below which I put together from some examples online:

```
Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
options.put("driver", MYSQL_DRIVER);
options.put("user", MYSQL_USERNAME);
options.put("password", MYSQL_PWD);
options.put("url", MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL); 
options.put("dbtable", "(select emp_no, emp_id from employees) as employees_data");
options.put("lowerBound", "10001");
options.put("upperBound", "499999");
options.put("numPartitions", "10");

DataFrame jdbcDF = sqlContext.load("jdbc", options);
```

This gets an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

I doubt that we can't give "as employees_data" for an Oracle query, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code has references like MYSQL_DRIVER; are you really connecting to an Oracle database, or a MySQL database?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to change the variable name... the values inside the variable are using Oracle drivers private static final String MYSQL_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
    private static final String MYSQL_USERNAME = "qauser";
    private static final String MYSQL_PWD = "qauser";
    private static final String MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL ="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//";

Answer (score 5):

> I doubt that we can't give "as employees_data" for an Oracle query

You may doubt it, but you can't use `AS` for a table alias in Oracle. You can for column aliases, where it is optional, but it is not allowed for table aliases. You can see that [in the syntax diagram](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2126863).

Assuming Spark doesn't mind the alias itself, you can just remove the `AS`:

```
options.put("dbtable", "(select emp_no, emp_id from employees) employees_data");
```

Comment: Worse, he's trying to alias the entire result set with those brackets! "(select emp_no, emp_id from employees) as employees_data"

Comment: @MichaelBroughton - I *think* that's OK, [from the Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html); the `dbtable` entry says it can be whatever can be in a `from` clause and "instead of a full table you could also use a subquery in parentheses", so this would be OK on that basis. Not sure the alias is actually useful though. I've never used this though (or seen it before...)

Comment: If it is passing that string to Oracle, I get that same ORA-00933 error with "(select 1 from dual) as mydual"

Comment: Yes, but you'd also get it from `select * from (select 1 from dual) as mydual`, which is what I *think* Spark is doing - using whatever is in `dbtable` as the `from`. But that is just from scanning that doc, so may be wrong *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole if i don't use the alias "as employees_data", spark gives me Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00903: invalid table name, I have tested this query using JdbcRDD works fine , since JDBCRDD is discouraged against the datasource API

Comment: Not having access to Spark - I'll bow out of the discussion. Maybe removing the "AS" keyword will work. I hope so for the OPs sake!

Comment: @prakash - you can have an alias, just not the `AS` keyword. But it doesn't look like it should be necessary. Are you sure schema `qauser` has an `employees` table? Or at least access to one without qualifying it, e.g. as `from hr.employees`?

Comment: @AlexPoole yes it has, tested the same query with same username and configuration in JdbcRDD API works fine.

Comment: @prakash - what happens when you just remove the `as`?

Comment: @AlexPoole  It worked perfectly by removing the AS ,    options.put("dbtable", "(select emp_no, emp_id from employees) employees_data");   Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: @prakash please accept the answer, because it helped you and at least 2 other people.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this...**

```
Map < String, String > oracle_options = new HashMap<>()
oracle_options.put("driver", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
oracle_options.put("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@//hostName/instanceName);
oracle_options.put("dbtable", "tableName");
DataFrame dataFrame = hContext.read().format("jdbc").options(oracle_options).load().select(String col1,String col2.....));
```

Where hContext is HiveContex instance.
if you are using selection means where condition use as follows:

```
DataFrame dataFrame = hContext.read().format("jdbc").options(oracle_options).load().select(String col1,String col2.....)).where(String expr);
```